# How can I find the joint eigenvalues of two matrices in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

If the joint eigenvalues of matrices **A** and **B** are defined as the roots of the equation 
det(lambda * **A** - **B**) = 0,
how can I solve this in MATLAB?

In particular, I am not sure how exactly lambda is defined - it obviously needs to be a matrix or vector, as otherwise there would only be one joint eigenvalue. Also, I am not sure if there is any in-built function, or if, say, fzero for finding the roots of nonlinear functions needs to be used.

Comment: Since **A** and **B** are taken to be known coefficient matrices, lambda is defined via the requirement that that determinant is equal to zero, which yields a finite set of values that are roots of the characteristic polynomial of the system.  This problem is also referred to as a generalized eigenvalue problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in function for this.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html

```
[V,D] = eig(B,A);
```

`[V,D] = eig(A,B)` solves the system `det(A - lambda*B) == 0`. However, the desired system to solve is `det(A*lambda - B) == 0` and so the inputs are reversed to respect solving this system.

Comment: In case any confusion comes about, I'll note that `[V,D] = eig(A,B)` solves the system `det(A - lambda*B) == 0`, which has `A` and `B` inverted relative to the OP's ordering.

Comment: Thank you @TroyHaskin, edited response to reflect your observation.

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect Troy Haskin's comments.  The inversion of the inputs caught me off guard for a moment until I read the comments