# Joint eigenvalues of two matrices in R

Tags: r, matlab, eigenvalue

How can I calculate the joint eigenvalues of matrices **A** and **B** defined as the roots of the equation det(lambda * **A** - **B**) = 0 in R?

In Matlab, the function `[V,D] = eig(A,B)` accepts one or two matrices as input parameters (example: [How can I find the joint eigenvalues of two matrices in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551182)). The R function `e=eigen(A)` does not seem to have the same feature. Are there alternative ways to calculate the joint eigenvalues in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `geigen` package.

```
library(geigen)

A <- toeplitz(c(2,1))
B <- toeplitz(c(4,3))

jointEigen <- geigen(B, A)

lambda <- jointEigen$values[1]
det(lambda*A - B)
# 0
```

Comment: R is fun! Thank you!